# How to Prepopulate <rich:calendar> in JSF?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In My application I am pre-populating some data from the Server. When I assign the data for the `<rich:Calendar>` I am not able to see the date in the UI. I am trying to convert the string from the database to Date format. Kindly help.

**My JSF Code**

```
 <a4j:outputPanel>
<rich:calendar id="myCalendar" popup="true" mode="client"
  preloadDateRangeBegin="#{item.date}" preloadDateRangeEnd="#{item.date}"
     value="#{item.date}" showApplyButton="true"
    cellWidth="24px"cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px">
</rich:calendar>
 </a4j:outputPanel>
```

**Date Conversion I am Using**

```
 DateFormat dateForm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    Date date = dateForm.parse(lastRunDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `<f:converDateTime>`, and have the property `item.date` to be of type `Date`

  ```
   <rich:calendar id="myCalendar" popup="true" mode="client"
        value="#{item.date}" showApplyButton="true"
        cellWidth="24px"cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px">
       <f:converDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
   </rich:calendar>
  ```
- get rid of `preloadDateRangeX` attributes